# How do I evaluate this sum: :$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-n+n^2-\cdots+(-n)^k}$ and $k$ is positive integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Wolfram alpha showed after some calculations for  evaluation of this series :

$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-n+n^2-\cdots+(-n)^k}$  for example for $k=10$ ,

I have got this [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1-n%C2%B2-n%5E3%2Bn%5E4-n%5E5%2Bn%5E6-n%5E7%2Bn%5E8-n%5E9%2Bn%5E10%7D+n%3D3+to+infty) which it close to $0$.

**My question here is :** : How do I evaluate this sum: :$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-n+n^2-\cdots+(-n)^k}$$ ?

**Note:** I exclude the singularity points  just i would like to Know how do i evaluate it

Thank you for any help

Comment: It seems that you forgot the $n$ term in the input to WA.

Comment: I think you want $n^k$ to be $(-n)^k$.

Comment: I want the altern form in denominator

Comment: thanks  i would like a fixed  k with altern form in denominator !!!!

Comment: In my humble opinion, I think that this kind of series is very artificial. As you are young, don't waste too much time on deadends such as this one.

Comment: If k=10 the sum is small because the first term (n=3) is already small and all the others are even smaller. Nothing remarkable here.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
The denominator can be written as 
$$\sum_{j=0}^k (-n)^j$$
And this has a closed form:
$$\frac{1-(-n)^{k+1}}{n+1} = \frac{n(-n)^k+1}{n+1}$$
From here there is no way to clean up the sum a lot more with elementary methods. More than likely you will require special functions.

**Edit:**
In case the OP wants a little more, if we sum the reciprocal of the above fraction from $n=3$ to $n=m$ and do a bit of rearranging we can write the sum as:
$$\sum_{n=3}^m \frac{1}{\sum_{j=0}^k (-n)^j} = \frac{(-1)^{k}\bigg(\zeta(k,3)-\zeta(k,m+1)\bigg)}{k+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

The denominator is a geometric series which we have a formula for.  So the summand is the reciprocal of that formula:

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{1-(-n)^{k+1}}.$$

Assuming convergence, you can split this into two sums.

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n}{1-(-n)^{k+1}}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-(-n)^{k+1}}.$$

These are going to be some sort of Digamma functions.

Comment: My scratch paper has the minus sign.  Stand by.